# How to disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer disable in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I need to disable the interactivePopGestureRecognizer in my App,I did

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Disable iOS 7 back gesture

 if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) 
{

 self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    }
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Enable iOS 7 back gesture

    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
 {

 self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;

 }
}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer

{

 return NO;
}
```

It works for 'iOS8' ,I have an Issue on 'iOS9'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer global,you can disable it after create the navigationController as bellow.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
nav.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled=NO;
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a code.The above I did is not supported for iOS9

Comment: Do you want to disable interactivePopGestureRecognizer global?